# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Datetime issue

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012, sql-import-wizard

I need to import a flat csv file with datetime column - 'ExecutionDateTime'. This column can have empty values, example :

[image]

I am  importing this to an existing table with ExecutionDateTime Column is set as Datetime2.

```
ExecutionDateTime   datetime2,
```

When I import using SQL Server Import Export wizard, I get value as "**0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000**", for the empty row. I want it to Read NULL.

ExecutionDateTime Column is set as Datetime2.

Current behavior:

[image]

Expected :

[image]
Is this possible?

I am using SQL Server 2012.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the wizard. But, you could use a case statement on the import...

```
insert into mytable
select
   Id
   ,case when ExecutionDateTime = '' then null else ExecutionDateTime end
from --openrowset, etc...
```

Or, you could always fix it after the fact if the data set is small 0r you are using a staging table...

```
update mytable 
set ExecutionDateTime = null
where ExecutionDateTime = ''
```

Here's an example using [BULKINSERT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/123303/95107)

Comment: Thanks. I did the update statement to fix it. I was wondering if there is any settings in Wizard that can take care of this issue.